# How to get correct Location of web elements in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I'm using `element.location` in selenium under python 3 to find the X, Y coordinates of a given element but I don't get exact values? Any ideas why or what I should do?

Comment: What do you mean by "exact"? Please read [ask] and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

It could depend on the size of the window. I have tried with different size and locations were different.

Try to set the size for browser:

`browser.set_window_size(1920, 1080)`

Hope, this will help you.